# Fixing all pip and package manager incompatibilities

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, python, pacman

I have installed some Python packages with `pip` and some others with my package manager (`pacman`). Now, every time I want to update the system, it says that some files already exist, because it tries to install some dependency Python module which actaully I already have. How can I fix this issue?

To reproduce the issue, you can simply try to install something via `pip` and then the same package via a package manager, i.e.:

> $ sudo pip install numpy

and then

> $ sudo pacman -S python-numpy

Comment: Try to paste (as text) exactly the errors you get...

Comment: thing like "python-docutils: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docutils/writers/_html_base.py exists in filesystem"

Comment: @slm  the problem _can_ be reproduced by simpling installing something with `pip` and then trying to install it via any package manager. It is also Linux related and many users have this kind of problem (just google it to check)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### WARNING: this answer uses the `--force` option of the `pacman` command. You should use it if and only if you understand what you are doing!

1. Export the list of packages installed through `pip`:

> >>> pip freeze > packages.txt

2. Launch this command: it will re-download and install through `pacman` packages installed from `pip` that are not marked as `installed` in the `pacman` database.

> >>> for i in $(awk -F "==" '{print $1}' packages.txt); do sudo pacman -S --needed --force --noconfirm python-$i; done

3. You can do the same with `python2` by just adding `2` after`python` and `pip` in the above commands.
4. Since now on, just use `pacman`, not `pip`. You can use `pip` to upgrade/downgrade to a particular version a package, if needed.

If you like, you can also use a script version:

```
#!/bin/sh
pip freeze > packages.txt
for i in $(awk -F "==" '{print $1}' packages.txt)
do
     sudo pacman -S --needed --force --noconfirm python-$i
done
```

Save it to file, give execution permission to that file and run.

Comment: Recommedning the use of  `--force` for a large number of packages is irresponsible at best, and explicitly contrary to the pacman developers' advice.

Comment: Sorry, corrected with --overwrite

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem: `--overwrite` is supposed to be used *judiciously*.

Comment: If you have another _working_ solution, I'll be happy to use it :)

Comment: Read the [warning note](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#.22Failed_to_commit_transaction_.28conflicting_files.29.22_error). And my answer would work without endangering your system.

Comment: I know, and python modules are a proper example of when `--overwrite` should be used. Overwriting python files with others from the official repo _can't_ break the system, since the only thing that can happen is that some file installed by `pip` will no be removed, but neither used though.

Comment: I'm done arguing with someone who clearly doesn't understand how pacman or Arch works.

Comment: Read the comments on the other answer and, please, stop saying that others are ignorant just because you don't know how to defend your thesis.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could remove them the way you installed them, with `pip`.

If that doesn't work, [identify all files not owned by a package](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Identify_files_not_owned_by_any_package). You can use [lostfiles](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/lostfiles/) to do this. Then manually remove those files.

Then, going forward, either use pacman to install all your python (ruby, node, whatever) packages, or use the `--user` switch to install to your $HOME.

Comment: Sorry, I've had some connection trouble, but this was a "fake" question (I just discovered the solution by myself and it was a while that I was googling it without success) :(){:|:};:

Comment: I have hundreds of modules installed, removing them would break the system and re-installing them by hand is absurd.

Comment: Removing them would not "break the system". How you decide to reinstall them is up to you, but that part could be scripted.

Comment: If you write a few lines of script for removing files _just_ of `pip` we could merge the answers...

Comment: Yes, it breaks the system if you don't reinstall them and if you are not sure that files you are removing are the ones that you are going to reinstall.